# Mouse curser gets "weird" when I move it between different monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse, cursor

I'm using a Windows 7 64-bit machine with two monitors side by side.

Sometimes when I have a fullsreen application running on my main monitor and I am moving the mouse curser between the two monitors, the curser gets corrupted. You cannot see that it is a curser anymore.

To fix it I have to restart the computer.

Has anyone heard about this problem before?  How do I fix it without rebooting?

Comment: Can you just restart explorer.exe instead of restarting the machine?

Comment: Have the same bug, two monitors with AMD card.

Answer (score 3):

I get a similar bug, but instead of the cursor disappearing, it looks like the tip of the cursor repeated below itself multiple times.

The only fix I've found it simply moving the cursor from monitor to monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. The only answer I've found by searching is: Dual monitors plus AMD driver bug. Try updating it, but it may not help.

Answer (score 0):

I did the next steps and it worked:
ControlPanel/Appearance&Personalization/AdjustScreenResolution. When you are on this screen(Change the Appearance Of Your Displays) make sure that the two **screens are the same size**. These screens are the blue rectangles under "Change the Appearance Of Your Displays". You can click on screen No1 and move to the top, or next to screen No2, or to the bottom, etc. The same thing you can do with Screen No2. *Now I have the rectangle of screen No1 and No2 with the same size next to each other, and my mouse can move easy without getting stock in this "invisible wall".*

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The OP has a corrupt cursor not a stuck cursor.